# How to Create smaller Button in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

It looks like that the minimum size button available in constraint layout is `88 X 44` I am trying to create a smaller button of `42dp x 28dp`, but its not creating it, if i define  the size from xml, it does not change the size, and display the default size button.

Kindly guide me how to change the size of button using constraint layout.

[image]

Comment: update your question with code you have tried.

Comment: try background="@null" else put the values in your xml layout

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the button view and go to properties and do the following:

1. Enter the minHeight property to 28dp
2. Enter the minWidth property to 42 dp

Similarly you can set  dimensions for  other views as well.